# How to minify nodejs code with webpack and use only import in the result bundle?

Tags: node.js, webpack, import, module, require

I have an nodejs application written by using esm module. So in my whole nodejs code I use import and export. I want to minify and bundle my code with webpack without dependencies, I'll keep node_modules folder next to the bundled file. My problem is that webpack always generate the bundle with require instead of import to import libraries, even when I specifie module options in my webpack configuration file. I have to use import because some of the libraries I used, like D3js don't work with require.

This is the webpack configuration I created:

```js
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'

export default {
    devServer: {
        server: 'https',
    },
    entry: './server.js',
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: '/Users/test/Documents/test/back/dist',
        module: true,
        chunkFormat: 'module',
        chunkLoading: 'import'
    },
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: './views', to: 'views' }
            ]
        })
    ],
}
```

Does someone have an idea about what I did wrong ? Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found how to generate my bundle using import instead of require to import external libraries. I have to use the "externalsType" option from webpack and "importType" option from webpack-node-externals.

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externalstypemodule
https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals#optionsimporttype-commonjs

This is the final webpack configuration:

```js
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'
import nodeExternals from 'webpack-node-externals'

export default {
    devServer: {
        server: 'https',
    },
    entry: './server.js',
    experiments: {
        outputModule: true,
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: '/Users/test/Documents/test/back/dist',
        chunkFormat: 'module',
    },
    target: 'node',
    mode: 'production',
    externalsType: 'module',
    externals: [nodeExternals({
        importType: 'module'
    })],
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: './views', to: 'views' }
            ]
        })
    ],
}
```